# How do you format text via JavaScript API within a CKEditor textbox?

Tags: ckeditor

Note: I am not looking to format an entire element a selection occurs in or to use the toolbar or working from within a plugin.  The formatting commands will be sent via socket.io so I need a way to format selected text from outside of the CKEditor codebase (any ideas on how to make specific selections would be welcome as well, especially if there is some way to either select text without rendering that selection at the same time and/or formatting text based on start-end/length parameters such that the same result would be achieved  - though this isn't an absolute requirement for me, I'd be happy being able to format just the selected text with things like font name, size, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with the following methods incase anyone is looking for a solution:

---

$('#' + Document.ID + '_contents iframe').contents()[0].execCommand('forecolor',false,'#00ff00');

$('#' + Document.ID + '_contents iframe').contents()[0].execCommand('JustifyCenter', false, null);

$('#' + Document.ID + '_contents iframe').contents()[0].execCommand('fontsize', false, 15);

$('#' + Document.ID + '_contents iframe').contents()[0].execCommand('fontname', false, names);